# python3 sched: schedule events after run()

Tags: python, python-3.x

When scheduling events using `scheduler.enter` after calling `scheduler.run` these events are fired not until at least one event that was entered before running the scheduler was fired. Is this intended?

```
import sched
import threading
import time

now = time.time()

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


def fire(name):
    print('EVENT:', name, time.time() - now)


def start():
    t = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)
    t.start()


###################################
# when scheduling all before start() everything works as expected.

# scheduler.enter(4, 1, fire, ('D',))
# scheduler.enter(3, 1, fire, ('C',))
# scheduler.enter(2, 1, fire, ('B',))
# scheduler.enter(1, 1, fire, ('A',))
# start()
#
# EVENT: A 1.0
# EVENT: B 2.0
# EVENT: C 3.0
# EVENT: D 4.0

###################################
# here I'd expect event 'A' to fire after one second. But it is
# not fired until at least one of the events scheduled before run() 
# is fired.

# scheduler.enter(2, 1, fire, ('B',))
# scheduler.enter(4, 1, fire, ('D',))
# start()
# scheduler.enter(1, 1, fire, ('A',))
# scheduler.enter(3, 1, fire, ('C',))
#
# EVENT: A 2.005021572113037
# EVENT: B 2.005021572113037
# EVENT: C 3.0050315856933594
# EVENT: D 4.0050413608551025

###################################
# starting before any event is scheduled is not possible,
# because run() returns directly.
# 
# start()
# scheduler.enter(3, 1, fire, ('C',))
# scheduler.enter(2, 1, fire, ('B',))
# scheduler.enter(1, 1, fire, ('A',))
#
# -- no events fired.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start the scheduler, it finds the delay until the next event, and calls the delayfunc (`time.sleep()`) with that value.  Until the delayfunc returns, the scheduler cannot fire any further events.

I don't see any way around this with the `sched` module.  Its design seems to be based on the idea that new events will be added from the handlers of existing events, rather than coming from a separate thread (indeed, it didn't even support use in a multi-threaded environment until Python 3.3).  There's probably a better way to do this using the new `async` stuff, but I don't have any particular recommendation.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this using the "new `async` stuff"?

Answer (score 0):

Remember you might also use `schedule` if you can decompose your task into regularly recurring standing jobs.

But in cases like this, my solution is to subclass scheduler as shown, polling with an inexpensive private function.  This makes the scheduler permanent, and it "hears" updates at (at least) the granularity of the polling interval.  I've set a configurable poll rate, defaulting to 4 times a second -- nice for GUI feedback.  In production the running thread should be a daemon so it won't interfere with termination requests.  Here's a modified version of your code.  Remove the `print('tick')` from poll when you're ready to use.

```
import sched
import threading
import time

now = time.time()

class scheduler_with_polling(sched.scheduler):
    def __init__(self, timefn, waitfn, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(timefn, waitfn)
        self.polling_interval = kwargs.get('polling_interval', 0.25)

    def run(self):
        self.enter(self.polling_interval, 1, self.__poll)
        super().run()

    def __poll(self):
        print('tick') # remove for production
        self.enter(self.polling_interval, 1, self.__poll)
        pass


scheduler = scheduler_with_polling(time.time, time.sleep, polling_interval=0.2)

def fire(name):
    print('EVENT:', name, time.time() - now)


def start():
    t = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run) # use daemon=True for production
    t.start()

scheduler.enter(2, 1, fire, ('B',))
scheduler.enter(4, 1, fire, ('D',))
start()
scheduler.enter(1, 1, fire, ('A',))
scheduler.enter(3, 1, fire, ('C',))
```